# c++ operator overloading code have no data ouput

Tags: c++

```
class mod5
{
private:
  unsigned i;

public:
  mod5() : 
    i{} 
  { 
  }

  mod5(mod5 const&) = default;
  mod5& operator=(mod5 const&) = default;

  explicit mod5(unsigned value) :
    i{value}
  {
  }

  unsigned mod_value() const
  {
    return i % 5;
  }

  friend auto operator<=>(mod5 const& lhs, mod5 const& rhs) 
  {
    return lhs.mod_value() <=> rhs.mod_value();
  }
};


std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, mod5& m)
{
  unsigned int temp;
  if(is >> temp ){
    m = mod5(temp);
  }
  else{
    is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
  }

  return is;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, mod5 const& m)
{
  os << m.mod_value();
  return os;
}

//=============================================================================
```

The code has been compiled successfully, but there will be no data when the file is added and run. I want to know which step is wrong?
The result of running is as shown below。
`rel_demo: operator==():  rel_demo: operator<():  rel_demo: operator>():  stack(0):`
The data does not seem to be well imported resulting in no data flow output.
The problem lies in the function of std::ostream& operator<<? Or is it on the function of std::istream& operator>>?

Comment: So the problem is that it doesn't read the file, and operator overloading has **nothing at all** to do with the problem?

Comment: no data ouput. the problem should be before the function std::optional<unsigned> string_to_unsigned(std::string const& str).

Comment: so the problem is that it doesn't read the file, correct? it thinks the file is empty?

Comment: yea. i think that function have some problem

Comment: why do you show us all this operator overloading code if it has nothing to do with the problem?

Comment: so I just show the code that needs to be fixed？

Comment: nobody is going to answer your question about "why does the program think the file is empty" if they have to read three hundred lines of completely unrelated code

Comment: yea i change it and only have the code need to fix

Comment: This code doesn't print anything because there isn't a main function